# join equivalent for subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be the join equivalent for sql syntax bellow:

```
select * from legislative where id in 
  (select id_legislative from legislative_domeniu where id_domeniu in 
    (select domeniu_id from account_domeniu  where account_id=$user_id)
  ) 
order by data_modified desc limit 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably look like this:

```
select l.*
from legislative l join
     legislative_domeniu ld
     on l.id = ld.id_legislative join
     account_domeniu d
     on ld.id_domeniu = d.domeniu_id
where d.account_id = $user_id
order by l.data_modified desc
limit 12;
```

The "probably" depends on duplicates generated by the underlying tables.  Your structure looks like a junction table between two entities, and this usually doesn't have duplicates.

If this is a problem, then the simplest way is `select distinct`:

```
select distinct l.*
from legislative l join
     legislative_domeniu ld
     on l.id = ld.id_legislative join
     account_domeniu d
     on ld.id_domeniu = d.domeniu_id
where d.account_id = $user_id
order by l.data_modified desc
limit 12;
```